# Momentum of Light Question

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, momentum

Since light beams carry momentum, why would a person holding a flashlight not feel a recoil similar to that of a rifle being fired?

Comment: Because they have extremely little momentum when compared to a bullet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am looking for one that is more in-depth. I believe I should talk about photons and such, I cannot formulate a strong answer, however.

Comment: To a significant extent, @JavierBadia's comment *is* the "more in-depth" version. That really is all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

One can do a simple calculation. Suppose you hold a $60\text{W}$ lightbulb and you turn it on. Each second it emits $60 \text{J}$ of energy. Using the energy-momentum relation for photons, $E=pc$, we get a momentum of $p = 60\text{J}/c = 2\cdot 10^{-6}\ \text{kg}\cdot\text{m}/\text{s}$, or a force $F = 2\cdot 10^{-6}\ \text{N}$. In contrast, a [Wikipedia page about firearms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_of_firearms) says that each bullet of a .44 Remington Magnum comes out with a momentum of roughly $5\ \text{kg}\cdot\text{m}/\text{s}$. That's quite a bit more than the flashlight.

(I should make a disclaimer that I know nothing about guns, I just pulled the numbers from Wikipedia. When we have a difference of six orders of magnitude, you don't really care about these things.)

Comment: $(60\ \mathrm{J})/(3\times10^8\ \mathrm{m/s}) = 2\times10^{-7}\ \mathrm{m/s}$

Comment: @user10851 what is that quantity supposed to be?